HTTPS with python and own server apache
we have a python client (on windows) and an apache server (centos)
We want to enable SSL  connection between client and server so:
we generated certificate and private key like this on server:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out ./conf/server.crt -keyout ./conf/server.key -subj "......."

we have correctly configured httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf
Listen ${APACHE_HTTPS_PORT}
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

<VirtualHost _default_:${APACHE_HTTPS_PORT}>
    DocumentRoot "${SERVER_INSTALL}/htdocs"
    ServerName 192.168.0.166:${APACHE_HTTPS_PORT}
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "${SERVER_INSTALL}/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SERVER_INSTALL}/conf/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "${SERVER_INSTALL}/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "/${SERVER_INSTALL}/logs/ssl_request_log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>

And now on the client side we communicate with our server by providing the .crt and the .key
self.https = HTTPSConnection(host=self.host, port=self.port, key_file=self.key_file, cert_file=self.cert_file, context=self.context)
content_type = 'application/json'
body = json.dumps(valuesDico)
self.https.putrequest('POST', self.page)
self.https.putheader('Content-Type', content_type)
self.https.putheader('Content-Length', str(len(body)))
self.https.endheaders()
self.https.send(body.encode('utf-8'))
response = self.https.getresponse()

this works well, but I am a little surprised in terms of security to have to use the private key on the client side which will therefore be available on the workstation of all users
I tried to replace the private key with the public key on the client side but it doesn't work. In addition, the public key is normally already embedded in the certificate file.
is this a good practice ?
is it possible to use only public key in client side ?

"we have correctly configured httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf" -  Cert and key on the client side is not about validating the server certificate, but they get used as client certificate to authenticate the client. If these are required than you have explicitly configured your server to require client certificates.

So the server is private, not accessible from Internet? Because otherwise the common advice is to use cert from let's encrypt instead of generating one yourself.
